# Sum of count occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query:

```
SELECT num1
    -> from table4
    -> WHERE suffix IN ('mt', 'dn')
    -> GROUP BY num1
    -> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT suffix) = 2;
```

That shows me following:

```
1563866656871111 
1563866656876839 
1563866656878888 
1563867854324841
```

How can I get just a number 4 instead?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: `select 4` ???  What are you trying to really do?

Comment: if you just want the count put select count(num1) as count .... then you will get 3, but not 4

Comment: Sorry it was quoted wrongly there should've been four rows of numbers

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). And please note that there is an Edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after your question modification it seems you need below

```
SELECT num1
FROM table4
WHERE suffix IN ('mt', 'dn')
GROUP BY num1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT suffix)!<>2
```

Comment: Your solution shows somehow this output:



2
2
2
2

I think there is a problem with having count (DISTINCT suffix) = 2

Comment: @vladpoverin share sample table data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap your existing query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT num1
    FROM table4
    WHERE suffix IN ('mt', 'dn')
    GROUP BY num1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT suffix) = 2
) x
```

Note: given your example data, this will return `3`, not `4`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want count of rows  then you will get it with this.

```
SELECT COUNT(x.num1)
    FROM (
        SELECT num1
        FROM table4
        WHERE suffix IN ('mt', 'dn')
        GROUP BY num1
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT suffix) = 2
    ) x
```